# I have not been able to make the tests for some functions inside a React setState

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a component in **React** that does a setState of a date that I convert to a toLocalString and I need to test using **Jest** that function, any ideas?

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [timestamp, setTimeStamp] = useState({});

  const convertDateToZoneTime = ({ date = new Date(), offset }) => {
  const dateTimeZone = new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: offset,
    hourCycle: 'h23',
    day: '2-digit',
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
  });

  return dateTimeZone;
};

useEffec(() => {
  setTimestamp({ dateString: new Date, localTime: convertDateToZoneTime(new Date) }); // I would like to make a test for convertDateToZoneTime
}, []);
}
```

Comment: What your `MyComponent ` returns? Do you render `timestamp` info in some element?

Comment: Could you define `convertDateToZoneTime` outside of the component function? If so, you could then export it for the test.